# Stochastic power iteration for generalized eigenvalue problems?

Tags: linear-algebra, iterative-method

Suppose $\mathbf{x}$ is a random variable in $n$ dimensions, and $u$ is a vector. How can I estimate the following quantity in an online fashion?

$$f(x)=\max_{\|u\|=1} \frac{ E\left[\langle u\cdot x\rangle ^4\right]}{E\left[\langle u\cdot x\rangle ^2\right]}$$

For a simpler problem of finding $\operatorname{argmax}_{\|u\|=1}E[\langle x \cdot u \rangle^2]$ the following method [is known](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.02456.pdf) to quickly converge:

$$u_{t+1}\leftarrow (I+\nu_t xx')u_t, u_t \leftarrow u_t/\|u_t\|$$

Is there a modification that works for the problem above?

Toy example, take $\mathbf{x}$ sampled IID from the following data matrix
$$\text{X=}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 5\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

We have $f(x)\approx 30.2987$ satisfied for $u\approx (0.520138, 0.854082)$

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-fourth-order-computation.nb)

Comment: Is thre any assumption on the distribution of $\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: I figured out an efficient way to do this for Gaussian $x$ with known diagonal covariance, so I'm interested in update that works for Gaussian with unknown covariance, but ideally, without any assumptions at all

Comment: Well, surely if $x$ is distributed based on some complicated, perhaps multimodal, distribution, the only way you can solve this is by sampling.

Comment: Right, it needs to be stochastic. A similar problem is to estimate $\|E[xx^T]\|$, and it's easy to do by iterating $u=x x^Tu; u=u/\|u\|$ which works well (stochastic Power Method), I'm wondering what a similar procedure would be in this case